# Shell Script to find pattern exists or not

Tags: bash, shell, grep, pattern-matching

I want to search for the pattern `nfs /dev/sda4` in a conf file using shell script. If exist I just need to ignore it if not present I need to add that pattern

Answer (score 3):

This will insert the line `nfs /dev/sda4` at the top of the file if it's not found in the file:

```
grep -q 'nfs /dev/sda4' file || sed -i 'i\nfs \/dev\/sda4' file
```

Or at the bottom:

```
grep -q 'nfs /dev/sda4' file || sed -i '$a\nfs \/dev\/sda4' file
```